# Localstack - AWS API Gateway enabling binary support using Terraform

Tags: terraform, aws-api-gateway, localstack

I'm failing to enable binary support using the API Gateway with Terraform on Localstack.

The example is simple: a Lambda generates avatars similar to those of Github and returns the image as PNG.

The Lambda is (proxy) integrated with an API Gateway (the idea is: `GET /avatars/{username}` -> image/png)

When I invoke the published URL (I'm doing this on Localstack), the API returns always the Base64 Encoded image without applying the `CONVERT_TO_BINARY`.

Here are the basic steps...

1. Create the ReST API:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "api" {
  name = var.api_name
  
  # enable support for 'image/png'
  binary_media_types = [
    "image/png",
  ]
}
```

2. Create the `GET /avatars/{username}` endpoint:

```
# ReST API endpoint 'avatars'
resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "avatars" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.id
  parent_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.root_resource_id
  path_part   = "avatars"
}

# 'avatars' endpoint resource path parameter.
resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "resource" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.id
  parent_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.avatars.id
  path_part   = "{username}"
}

# Defines the resource HTTP method (verb or action).
resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "get-avatar" {
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.id
  resource_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.resource.id
  http_method   = "GET"
  authorization = "NONE"

  request_parameters = {
    "method.request.path.username" = true
  }
}
```

3. Integrate the `GET /avatars/{username}` endpoint into the ReST API:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "resource_integration" {
  rest_api_id             = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.id
  resource_id             = aws_api_gateway_resource.resource.id
  http_method             = aws_api_gateway_method.get-avatar.http_method
  type                    = "AWS_PROXY"
  integration_http_method = "POST"
  uri                     = aws_lambda_function.lambda.invoke_arn
  passthrough_behavior    = "WHEN_NO_MATCH"

  request_parameters = {
    "integration.request.path.id" = "method.request.path.username"
  }
}
```

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_integration_response" "get-avatar-response" {
  rest_api_id      = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.id
  resource_id      = aws_api_gateway_resource.resource.id
  http_method      = aws_api_gateway_method.get-avatar.http_method
  status_code      = "200"
  content_handling = "CONVERT_TO_BINARY"
}
```

4. Deploy the ReST API:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "deployment" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.id
  stage_name  = "stage"
  depends_on  = [aws_api_gateway_method.get-avatar, aws_api_gateway_integration.resource_integration]
}
```

API Gateway assumes that the text data is a base64-encoded string and outputs the binary data as a base64-decoded blob.

Here the simple Lambda handler (in the awesome Go of course! :-) )

```golang
func handler(ctx context.Context, evt events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {
    log.Printf("Processing request data for request %s.\n", evt.RequestContext.RequestID)

    username := evt.PathParameters["username"]
    if len(username) == 0 {
        code := http.StatusBadRequest
        msg := http.StatusText(code)
        return events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{Body: msg, StatusCode: code}, nil
    }

    key := []byte{0x00, 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66, 0x77, 0x88, 0x99, 0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0xDD, 0xEE, 0xFF}
    icon := identicon.New7x7(key)

    log.Printf("creating identicon for '%s'\n", username)

    pngdata := icon.Render([]byte(username))
    
    body := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(pngdata) // <= Base64 Encoded Response

    return events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{
        Body: body,
        Headers: map[string]string{
            "Content-Type": "image/png",
        },
        IsBase64Encoded: true,  // <= Is Base64 Encoded? Yes!
        StatusCode:      200,
    }, nil
}
```

Invoking the endpoint with curl (for example):

```sh
curl 'http://localhost:4566/restapis/8nilx7bu49/stage/_user_request_/avatars/type-a-username-here'
```

...it responds with the Base64 encoded image. Infact, if I pipe the output to `base64 -d` saving the content, the image is right:

```sh
curl 'http://localhost:4566/restapis/8nilx7bu49/stage/_user_request_/avatars/type-a-username-here' -s | base64 -d > test.png
```

Could someone please point me out what I'm missing or confusing?

All the best,
Luca

Comment: I've been having the same issue, all research I've done so far points to the fact that the API Gateway implementation has no support for the binary media types.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by using "*/*" as binary_media_types and nothing else. I read somewhere that if you specify something the client needs to send an identical accept content header.

I also don't have a aws_api_gateway_integration_response resource.

And finally I'm returning the raw image bytes in the form of a ByteArray. I'm using Kotlin to implement my lambda but the below should give you an idea how how to do it.

```
@Get("/{id}/avatar")
fun getImage(id: Long): HttpResponse<ByteArray> {
    logger.info { "AvatarController.getImage($id)" }
    val image = avatarService.getImage(id)
    val bytes: ByteArray = IOUtils.toByteArray(image)
    return HttpResponse.ok(bytes).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE)
```

Don't Base64 encode and don't use APIGatewayProxyResponse.